# How to navigate to my mainpage with showing the mainpage's appbar?

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to develop an authentication process in my flutter app and I'm facing problems that the appbar vanishes when I redirect to my main page when I finish signing up or logging in.
I'm using go router to navigate to the main page and hidden_drawer_menu package to select the pages that I want to go.

Here's how the problem looks when I run the app. The second image is the result if I press the 'Log in' button in the first image.

[image: error1]
[image: error2]

## sidebar.dart

```
import 'package:app/pages/achievement_page.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/challenge_list_page.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/main_page.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/tree_design_page.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/settings_page.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hidden_drawer_menu/hidden_drawer_menu.dart';

class SideBar extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routename = "/";
  const SideBar({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<SideBar> createState() => _SideBarState();
}

class _SideBarState extends State<SideBar> {
  List<ScreenHiddenDrawer> _pages = [];

  final _baseStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontSize: 14,
    color: Colors.black,
  );

  final _selectedStyle = const TextStyle(
    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
    fontSize: 24,
    color: Colors.white,
  );

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _pages = [
      //main page
      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Hello there!',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        const MainPage(),
      ),

      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Select your tree!',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        const TreeDesignPage(),
      ),

      //achievement page
      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Achievement',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        const AchievementPage(),
      ),

      //challenge list page
      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Challnge',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        const ChallngeListPage(),
      ),

      //setting page
      ScreenHiddenDrawer(
        ItemHiddenMenu(
          name: 'Settings',
          baseStyle: _baseStyle,
          selectedStyle: _selectedStyle,
        ),
        const SettingsPage(),
      ),
    ];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return HiddenDrawerMenu(
      backgroundColorMenu: const Color.fromRGBO(151, 193, 169, 1),
      screens: _pages,
      initPositionSelected: 0,
      slidePercent: 60,
    );
  }
}
```

## router.dart

```
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';
import 'package:app/side_menu/sidebar.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/main_page.dart';

final router = GoRouter(
  routes: [
    GoRoute(
      path: SideBar.routename,
      builder: (context, state) => const SideBar(),
    ),
    GoRoute(
      path: "/mainpage",
      builder: (context, state) => const MainPage(),
    ),
  ],
);
```

## login_form_screen.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/constants/gaps.dart';
import 'package:app/constants/sizes.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/authentication/widgets/form_button.dart';
import 'package:app/view_models/login_view_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class LoginFormScreen extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const LoginFormScreen({super.key});

  @override
  ConsumerState<LoginFormScreen> createState() => _LoginFormScreenState();
}

class _LoginFormScreenState extends ConsumerState<LoginFormScreen> {
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  Map<String, String> formData = {};

  void _onSubmitTap() {
    if (_formKey.currentState != null) {
      if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
        _formKey.currentState!.save();
        ref
            .read(loginProvider.notifier)
            .login(formData["email"]!, formData["password"]!, context);
      }
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text('Log in'),
      ),
      body: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
          horizontal: Sizes.size36,
        ),
        child: Form(
            key: _formKey,
            child: Column(
              children: [
                Gaps.v28,
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Email',
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
                      return "I don't like your Email";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (newValue) {
                    if (newValue != null) {
                      formData['email'] = newValue;
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Gaps.v16,
                TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    hintText: 'Password',
                    enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      ),
                    ),
                    focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                      borderSide: BorderSide(
                        color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  validator: (value) {
                    if (value != null && value.isEmpty) {
                      return "Wrong password";
                    }
                    return null;
                  },
                  onSaved: (newValue) {
                    if (newValue != null) {
                      formData['password'] = newValue;
                    }
                  },
                ),
                Gaps.v28,
                GestureDetector(
                  onTap: _onSubmitTap,
                  child: FormButton(
                    disabled: ref.watch(loginProvider).isLoading,
                    text: "Log in",
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

## login_view_model.dart

```
import 'dart:async';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:app/resources/authentication_repo.dart';
import 'package:app/utils/utils.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class LoginViewModel extends AsyncNotifier<void> {
  late final AuthenticationRepository _repository;

  @override
  FutureOr<void> build() {
    _repository = ref.read(authRepo);
  }

  Future<void> login(
    String email,
    String password,
    BuildContext context,
  ) async {
    state = const AsyncValue.loading();
    state = await AsyncValue.guard(
      () async => await _repository.signIn(email, password),
    );
    if (state.hasError) {
      showFirebaseErrorSnack(context, state.error);
    } else {
      context.go("/mainpage");
    }
  }
}

final loginProvider = AsyncNotifierProvider<LoginViewModel, void>(
  () => LoginViewModel(),
);
```

## main_page.dart

```
import 'package:app/models/challenge_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:app/pages/tree_design_page.dart';
import 'package:app/models/tree_model.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

final challengeModelProvider =
    ChangeNotifierProvider<ChallengeModel>((ref) => ChallengeModel());

class MainPage extends StatefulWidget {
  static String routename = "/mainpage";
  const MainPage({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  State<MainPage> createState() => _MainPageState();
}

class _MainPageState extends State<MainPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          image: DecorationImage(
            image: AssetImage('images/green_meadow.jpg'),
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
        ),
        child: Stack(
          children: [
            // Background Image
            Positioned.fill(
              child: Image.asset(
                'images/green_meadow.jpg',
                fit: BoxFit.cover,
              ),
            ),
            // Overlay Image
            Align(
              alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Consumer(
                  builder: (context, WidgetRef ref, _) {
                    final int numberofAchievements = ref
                        .read(challengeModelProvider)
                        .numberofAchienements(); // 오류 수정
                    return Image(
                      image: AssetImage(treeModelList[selectedtreeindex].path),
                      //make tree bigger
                      width: 200 + numberofAchievements * 100,
                      height: 200 + numberofAchievements * 100,
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```